# How to filter out a range of numbers from another range

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to create an IntStream in Java 8, from which I'd like to filter out another range. For instance, if I have the following array :

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ..., 20}
```

I'd like to keep all except: `{4, 5, 6, 7}`

I created the following IntStream:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20);
```

However, I'd like the possibility of doing some kind of :

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).filter(IntStream.rangeClosed(4, 7));
```

Is there a way to do so? Apparently, there's no way to do that, but I may be mistaken. Thanks in advance for any reply

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with a simple range check?

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).filter(i -> i < 4 || i > 7)
```

Comment: Thanks, I could indeed do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make two streams and concat? 1-3 and 8-20?

[`IntStream.concat(IntStream, IntStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#concat-java.util.stream.IntStream-java.util.stream.IntStream-)

By doing that you skip the checking for each element.

Another suggestion is to convert it to two sets and do

```
range1.boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
range2.boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

range1.removeAll(range2);
```

Comment: But may be he has requirement of filtering existing range where you dont know the elements to be removed in future

Comment: Yes, that may be the case, but it was not stated. So i did not assume anything.

Comment: @Ghanshyam Bagul: I don’t see a significant difference between `IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(1,4),IntStream.rangeClosed(8,20))` and `IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(r1,r2),IntStream.rangeClosed(e2+1,e1))`.

Comment: Thanks. I do exactly know what I have to exclude. Those values will never change. So I guess I could go with concat. But in short, the answer is NO. You cannot remove one range from another, it seems.

Comment: @DigitalSelf Added suggestion for using sets also